# ordering the list of tuples based on the elements in other list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have 2 lists as shown below. I wish to sort list `list100` based on the order of elements in `list50`

```
list50 = ['cat', ,'bat', 'cat', 'cat', 'bat', 'No Data', 'bat', 'No Data']
list100 = [('cat', 100),
  ('cat', 100),
  ('cat', 100),
  ('bat', 67),
  ('bat', 67),
  ('bat', 67),
  ('No Data', 40),
  ('No Data', 40)]
```

I desire to turn the list `list100` to

```
[('cat', 100),
  ('bat', 67),
  ('cat', 100),
  ('cat', 100),
  ('bat', 67),
  ('No Data', 40),
  ('bat', 67),
  ('No Data', 40)
  ]
```

Is there any method of making it possible ?

Comment: Are two tuples with the same first element guaranteed to have the second element too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert `list100` into a dict and simply list the items in `list50` with their values in the dict:

```
d = dict(list100)
[(k, d[k]) for k in list50]
```

This returns:

```
[('cat', 100), ('bat', 67), ('cat', 100), ('cat', 100), ('bat', 67), ('No Data', 40), ('bat', 67), ('No Data', 40)]
```

Comment: Why sort when sorting isn't needed at all to produce the desired result in a more efficient manner?

Comment: ... *based on the order of elements in `list50`*

Comment: @FilipMłynarski But you are not the OP. Does the OP simply want the desired result, or does he/she actually need sorting involved as a requirement for the assignment?

Comment: The line [(k, d[k]) for k in list50] shuld have been list100=[(k, d[k]) for k in list50]

Comment: This answer works correctly only if   ('cat', 100),
  ('bat', 67), are constants . if you change   ('bat', 67),
  ('bat', 67), to   ('bat', 6),
  ('bat', 67), code works wrong

Comment: What is the number of elements in the List and Tuple are not same. This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the function `sorted()` with a key you can convert the list `list50` into the dictionary of lists, where each list contains indices of the coorresponding element in `list50`. Each time you call the key function you remove the last element from the list.

```
list50 = ['cat', 'bat', 'cat', 'cat', 'bat', 'No Data', 'bat', 'No Data']
list100 = [('cat', 100), ('cat', 100), ('cat', 100), ('bat', 67), ('bat', 67), ('bat', 67), ('No Data', 40), ('No Data', 40)]

lookup = {}
for num, el in enumerate(list50):
    lookup.setdefault(el, []).append(num)       
# print(lookup)
# {'cat': [0, 2, 3], 'bat': [1, 4, 6], 'No Data': [5, 7]}     

list100_ = sorted(list100, key=lambda x: lookup[x[0]].pop())   
# [('cat', 100), ('bat', 67), ('cat', 100), ('cat', 100), ('bat', 67), ('No Data', 40), ('bat', 67), ('No Data', 40)]
```

If you want to keep the order of tuples with equal first elements as in the original list use deque and the method `popleft()` to pop the first element from the list:

```
list50 = ['cat', 'bat', 'cat', 'cat', 'bat', 'No Data', 'bat', 'No Data']
list100 = [('cat', 1), ('cat', 2), ('cat', 3), ('bat', 1), ('bat', 2), ('bat', 3), ('No Data', 1), ('No Data', 2)]

from collections import deque

lookup = {}
for num, el in enumerate(list50):
    lookup.setdefault(el, deque()).append(num)
# print(lookup)
# {'cat': deque([0, 2, 3]), 'bat': deque([1, 4, 6]), 'No Data': deque([5, 7])}     

list100_ = sorted(list100, key=lambda x: lookup[x[0]].popleft())
#[('cat', 1), ('bat', 1), ('cat', 2), ('cat', 3), ('bat', 2), ('No Data', 1), ('bat', 3), ('No Data', 2)]
```